# What tools can run scripts on multiple windows servers?

Tags: scripting, windows, automation

I'm looking for a tool that can schedule a job (shell script, vbs, powershell) on 100+ standalone Windows servers.

I know Altiris can do that, but I think it needs an agent on every server. I prefer an agentless (affordable) solution.

Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The software which can del with it is for instance Windows PowerShell ISE, which you can download here (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595). Scripts necessary for you to run your own scripts on multiple computers are listed here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/30/learn-how-to-run-powershell-scripts-against-multiple-computers.aspx).The basic idea is to make a list of your computers and then run script using PowerShell ISE. For example if you store the list in file and want to define the name, manufacturer and version for every computer in the list, you can use this script.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\fso\Computers.txt

Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios -cn $computers -EA silentlyContinue |

Format-table __Server, Manufacturer, Version –AutoSize
```

Similar suggestion with code as well you can find here (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/37cffcf0-533e-4d44-80a9-cc327c8545eb/).